# jQuery steps submit form -> step turns red

Tags: jquery-steps

After submitting my form, jQuery steps seems to consider the submit as failed. The last step turns red.
I did not find any documentation on this topic.
Is the plugin expecting a particular response (type) from the server?

```
  onFinishing: function() {

                debugger;
                var formData = $("#wizardSumbit").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("Wizard_Submit", "Wizard")', //serverside
                            data: formData,
                            beforeSend: function () {
                                //show loading image
                            },
                            success: function (result) {
                                console.log(result); //use this to see the response from serverside
                            },
                            error: function (e) {
                                console.log(e); //use this to see an error in ajax request
                            }
                        });
                 }
```

I am a little bit confused here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jQuery steps` is considering the submit as failed because of the missing `return=true` statement in the event.